# Pandas - 2 dataframes, add Index column of df1 to df2 on second column

Tags: pandas, merge, match

I have 2 dataframes :

```
df1 (sample, has more columns):

+---+----------------+--------------+-----------+
|   |     Region     | Placement ID |   Units   |
+---+----------------+--------------+-----------+
| 0 | Western Europe | 1.10872E+13  | 367628.76 |
| 1 | Western Europe | 1.10872E+13  | 367628.76 |
| 2 | Western Europe | 1.10872E+13  | 74604.63  |
+---+----------------+--------------+-----------+

df2 (sample, has more columns:

+-----------+----------------+--------------+
| Creatives | Publisher Name | Placement ID |
+-----------+----------------+--------------+
| Temenos   | Quantcast      | 1.10872E+13  |
| Temenos   | Quantcast      | 1.10872E+13  |
| Temenos   | Quantcast      | 1.10872E+13  |
+-----------+----------------+--------------+
```

What I would like to do is to add an extra column in dataframe 2 with the index column of dataframe 1 based on Placement ID.

Some placements Id fields in dataframe 1 or 2 might be empty, or have erroneous value, in case there is no match, or an error is found, then I would like to add a Missing or Error value such as N/A, Missing, or leave blank

Comment: there are many many many existing SO questions demonstrating the use of `.join` and `.merge` with pandas dataframes

Comment: Hi Paul, thank you for the quick reply. But I can't find one that allows to:

a. Shows me how to merge and join the index of one dataframe to another
b. I can't seem to find a way, or rather, understand, how to just add 1 extra column rather than merge all dataframes

Any help here would be appreciated

Comment: just select only the columns that you need (your join key and value fields)

Comment: your example should also include your desired output. right now your request is ambiguous b/c there are multiple values for the index of `df1` for the `Placement ID` shown.

Answer (score 1):

IIUC you need [`merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.merge.html), but there is problem with duplicates, so first remove them by [`drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) and then select columns one for adding and another for join (`Placement ID`):

```
print (pd.merge(df2, 
                df1.drop_duplicates('Placement ID')[['Units', 'Placement ID']], 
                how='left', 
                on='Placement ID'))


  Creatives Publisher Name  Placement ID      Units
0   Temenos      Quantcast  1.108720e+13  367628.76
1   Temenos      Quantcast  1.108720e+13  367628.76
2   Temenos      Quantcast  1.108720e+13  367628.76
```

If need add index need [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html):

```
print (pd.merge(df2, 
                df1.drop_duplicates('Placement ID')
                   .reset_index()[['level_0','Placement ID']], 
                how='left', 
                on='Placement ID'))
  Creatives Publisher Name  Placement ID  level_0
0   Temenos      Quantcast  1.108720e+13        0
1   Temenos      Quantcast  1.108720e+13        0
2   Temenos      Quantcast  1.108720e+13        0
```

Need drop duplicates, because `merge` multiple rows by joined keys - there are 3 same values `1.108720e+13` in `df2` and 3 rows in `df1`, so get 3 x 3 rows like:

```
print (pd.merge(df2, 
                df1.reset_index()[['level_0', 'Placement ID']], 
                how='left', 
                on='Placement ID'))

  Creatives Publisher Name  Placement ID  level_0
0   Temenos      Quantcast  1.108720e+13        0
1   Temenos      Quantcast  1.108720e+13        1
2   Temenos      Quantcast  1.108720e+13        2
3   Temenos      Quantcast  1.108720e+13        0
4   Temenos      Quantcast  1.108720e+13        1
5   Temenos      Quantcast  1.108720e+13        2
6   Temenos      Quantcast  1.108720e+13        0
7   Temenos      Quantcast  1.108720e+13        1
8   Temenos      Quantcast  1.108720e+13        2
```

Comment: Hi jezrael, thanks for the quick reply. What I'd need is the index of df1 to be added to  df2 based on Placement IDs

Comment: @MatteoM that's an ambiguous request. there are three unique index values for the `Placement ID` in your example

Comment: @PaulH again sorry, I think it's my fault in not explaining my question to clearly.

Comment: @PaulH again sorry, I think it's my fault for not being clear.
DF1 contains data that allows me to calculate spend (e.g. price, way to calculate spend) for each item (Placement ID)
DF2 contains data that contains the figures of sales/purchase of each item

What I would like to do is to create a column in df2 that matches each line of df1 based on the Placement iD. In Power Pivot for excel, I would do this by creating an index column in DF1 for each line.
I can't do a simple match by Placement ID becaused have certain missing Placement IDs in our DF1, and excel wont allow duplicates

Comment: @MatteoM that clarified nothing. Add more data to your example and show your expected output.

Comment: @MatteoM - How does it works? Is desired output `0` in column `level_0` ?